# Read Binary file records in php

Tags: php, binaryfiles

I have created binary file using C codings. This is the structure of that binary file.

```
struct emp
{
   int eid,eage;
   char name[20],city[20];
}record;
```

Using this 'C' Structure i created a binary file called "table1.txt"

Now i want to show the contents of the file in a web page using php. How can i do this ?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>binary file</title></head>
<body style="background-color:yellow">
<?
$fp = fopen("table1.txt", "rb");
$read = fread($fp, 4); 
$n = unpack("i", $read);
$data1 = fread($fp, 8);
$nn = unpack("i",$data1);
echo $number[1]; 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have used the above code. But i can only read the first field of the file only. My first Record field is Employee id its values is '0'. The page displays only 0.

Comment: Could you post the contents of `bin2hex(file_get_contents('table1.txt'));`?

Comment: 0 25 xxxxx yyyyy
1 32 x1x1x yyyyy
2 33 x2x2x yyyyy

Note : There is no space or null characters between the fields.

Comment: That doesn't look like the real output of `bin2hex()` though ...

Comment: 000000001900000068656172746c790000000000000000000000000074757479000000000000000000000000000000003100000001000000190000006172756e006c7900000000000000000000000000747574790000000000000000000000000000000031000000020000001900000073697661006c7900000000000000000000000000747574790000000000000000000000000000000031000000030000001f00000073697661006c7900000000000000000000000000747574790000000000000000000000000000000031000000

This is the content of bin2hex(file_get_contents('table1.txt'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some strange reason, each data segment is not 48 bytes as expected but 52 bytes.

```
$f = fopen('data.txt', 'rb');

while (!feof($f)) {
  // read one segment of 52 bytes
  if ($s = fread($f, 52)) {
    // unpack the binary structure into an associative array
    print_r(unpack('ieid/ieage/a20name/a20city', $s));
  }
}

fclose($f);
```

Comment: It's not strange, it's called padding. For gcc add ____attribute____ ((____packed____)) to the definition of the struct. Though sizeof(record) returns 48 on 3 different platforms.

Comment: @strkol I imagined it had something to do with padding, but it's good to see that confirmed ... but why is it padded to 52 bytes?

Comment: I don't know. gcc doesn't insert any padding on this struct. I guess that Smith Dwayne is using some other compiler.

Comment: @strkol the weird thing is that the padding doesn't even consist of zeroes; it's (consistently) `0x31000000`

Comment: then it seems that the bug is in the C program which writes the txt file :-)

Comment: This code is working fine. I'm using GCC compiler only. How did u find that structure gets "52" bytes? What is padding?

Comment: @SmithDwayne I found the padding by aligning the chunks of data, starting with 48 bytes; after adding 4 bytes they aligned. Guess it doesn't matter anymore now, but now you know ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is 'C' Structure.
    struct gross
    {
        char date[11];
        char ac[128];
        char type[5];
        float mvalue;
        float netraw;
        float netfer;
        char stat[128];
        float firr;
        float acb;
    };

This is the content of binary file when compiled with GCC compiler.

> 12/12/1995    d   us  12.23   34.12   90.12   fees    12  56.12
>   01/01/1998    a   us  52.23   54.12   10.12   fees    92  16.12
>   31/12/1999    a   us  52.23   54.12   10.12   fees    92  16.12
>   31/12/1999    d   us  12.23   34.12   90.12   fees    12  56.12
>   01/01/2000    a   us  52.23   54.12   10.12   fees    92  16.12
>   01/01/2000    z   us  12.23   34.12   90.12   fees    12  56.12
>   31/12/2010    a   us  52.23   54.12   10.12   fees    92  16.12
>   31/12/2010    d   us  12.23   34.12   90.12   fees    12  56.12

This is the PHP coding to read the content of the above binary file.

```
echo "<table>";
while (!feof($f)) {

  if ($s = fread($f, 292)) {

        $nn = unpack('a11date/a128ac/a5type/fmvalue/fnetraw/fnetfer/a128stat/ffirr/facb', $s);

        echo "<td>" . $nn[date] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $nn[ac] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $nn[type] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $nn[mvalue] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $nn[netraw] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $nn[netfer] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $nn[stat] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $nn[firr] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $nn[acb] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
 }
}
        echo "</table>";
fclose($f);
?>
```

This is the answer i got from the above code. I'm getting lot of garbage values is second and seventh field. And How to set precision for the float fields.

> 12/12/1995    d¸³M·g·ew·¤dw·àew·Öúr·ÿÿÿÿ,w·ø;w·Ìª¹¿ô{·{·‹ây·Ð{·SpP·ip·¤dw·ew·€5w·ôOg·
>   X«¹¿»qP·äSg   us  12.229999542236 34.119998931885 90.120002746582 fees·5rP· #Ä äSg· rP·ô›Å #Ä 5rP·0#o·¸xw·x«¹¿·ÅÿÿýŽäSg·¸xw·ÆD¬¹¿L¬¹¿5rP·pòy· 12  56.119998931885
>
> 01/01/1998    a¸³M·g·ew·¤dw·àew·Öúr·ÿÿÿÿ,w·ø;w·Ìª¹¿ô{·{·‹ây·Ð{·SpP·ip·¤dw·ew·€5w·ôOg·
>   X«¹¿»qP·äSg   us  52.229999542236 54.119998931885 10.119999885559 fees·5rP· #Ä äSg· rP·ô›Å #Ä 5rP·0#o·¸xw·x«¹¿·ÅÿÿýŽäSg·¸xw·ÆD¬¹¿L¬¹¿5rP·pòy· 92  16.120000839233
>
> 31/12/1999    a¸³M·g·ew·¤dw·àew·Öúr·ÿÿÿÿ,w·ø;w·Ìª¹¿ô{·{·‹ây·Ð{·SpP·ip·¤dw·ew·€5w·ôOg·
>   X«¹¿»qP·äSg   us  52.229999542236 54.119998931885 10.119999885559 fees·5rP· #Ä äSg· rP·ô›Å #Ä 5rP·0#o·¸xw·x«¹¿·ÅÿÿýŽäSg·¸xw·ÆD¬¹¿L¬¹¿5rP·pòy· 92  16.120000839233
>
> 31/12/1999    d¸³M·g·ew·¤dw·àew·Öúr·ÿÿÿÿ,w·ø;w·Ìª¹¿ô{·{·‹ây·Ð{·SpP·ip·¤dw·ew·€5w·ôOg·
>   X«¹¿»qP·äSg   us  12.229999542236 34.119998931885 90.120002746582 fees·5rP· #Ä äSg· rP·ô›Å #Ä 5rP·0#o·¸xw·x«¹¿·ÅÿÿýŽäSg·¸xw·ÆD¬¹¿L¬¹¿5rP·pòy· 12  56.119998931885
>
> 01/01/2000    a¸³M·g·ew·¤dw·àew·Öúr·ÿÿÿÿ,w·ø;w·Ìª¹¿ô{·{·‹ây·Ð{·SpP·ip·¤dw·ew·€5w·ôOg·
>   X«¹¿»qP·äSg   us  52.229999542236 54.119998931885 10.119999885559 fees·5rP· #Ä äSg· rP·ô›Å #Ä 5rP·0#o·¸xw·x«¹¿·ÅÿÿýŽäSg·¸xw·ÆD¬¹¿L¬¹¿5rP·pòy· 92  16.120000839233
>
> 01/01/2000    z¸³M·g·ew·¤dw·àew·Öúr·ÿÿÿÿ,w·ø;w·Ìª¹¿ô{·{·‹ây·Ð{·SpP·ip·¤dw·ew·€5w·ôOg·
>   X«¹¿»qP·äSg   us  12.229999542236 34.119998931885 90.120002746582 fees·5rP· #Ä äSg· rP·ô›Å #Ä 5rP·0#o·¸xw·x«¹¿·ÅÿÿýŽäSg·¸xw·ÆD¬¹¿L¬¹¿5rP·pòy· 12  56.119998931885
>
> 31/12/2010    a¸³M·g·ew·¤dw·àew·Öúr·ÿÿÿÿ,w·ø;w·Ìª¹¿ô{·{·‹ây·Ð{·SpP·ip·¤dw·ew·€5w·ôOg·
>   X«¹¿»qP·äSg   us  52.229999542236 54.119998931885 10.119999885559 fees·5rP· #Ä äSg· rP·ô›Å #Ä 5rP·0#o·¸xw·x«¹¿·ÅÿÿýŽäSg·¸xw·ÆD¬¹¿L¬¹¿5rP·pòy· 92  16.120000839233
>
> 31/12/2010    d¸³M·g·ew·¤dw·àew·Öúr·ÿÿÿÿ,w·ø;w·Ìª¹¿ô{·{·‹ây·Ð{·SpP·ip·¤dw·ew·€5w·ôOg·
>   X«¹¿»qP·äSg   us  12.229999542236 34.119998931885 90.120002746582 fees·5rP· #Ä äSg· rP·ô›Å #Ä 5rP·0#o·¸xw·x«¹¿·ÅÿÿýŽäSg·¸xw·ÆD¬¹¿L¬¹¿5rP·pòy· 12  56.119998931885